# ORDER BY CASE to get this: -1, -2, -3, 0, +1, +2, +3

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

In my query I want to ORDER BY this:

```
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL cycle MONTH))
```

The above statement returns negative and positive values. More precisely negative for future dates, positive for past dates and zero for current date. I use it to calulate the expiration dates of a service. Below you can find a commented example of the output:

```
-1 (expires tomorrow)
-10 (expires in 10 days)
-20 (expires in 20 days)
0 (expires today)
+1 (expired yesterday)
+10 (expired 10 days ago)
+20 (expired 20 days ago)
```

The problem is that I want to ORDER BY results in the same exact way you see above. I'm trying with CAST() and ABS() with no success. I think that it's due to the fact that there are no standard functions to get what I want. Said that I'm pretty sure that I can slove this issue using ORDER BY CASE as follows.

Before you ask it's **pseudo code**. I'm not preteting to use this in my query:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN X <= 0 
THEN
ODER BY CASE WHEN X > 0
```

Too bad that I'm just getting tons of syntax errors with everything I try to use :-) How does it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a0dd/6

```
SELECT id, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL cycle MONTH)) idx
FROM test
ORDER BY IF(idx<0,-idx/1000,IF(idx=0,0.1, idx)) ASC
```

Comment: Thank you. I really like this approach. Thank you again a lot. I have no questions about your query. It's totally clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the ORDER BY at the end of the query

1. **SELECT** (query) as "xxx" **FROM DUAL**
2. **CASE** xxx
3. (case instructions)
4. **END AS** expiration
5. **ORDER BY** expiration

Answer (score 0):

You need to give yourself a few extra columns in your result to get the desired result to ORDER by.

For example:

```
SELECT (values you care about),
    DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL cycle MONTH)) AS number,
    ABS(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL cycle MONTH))) AS numberAbs,
    CASE WHEN 
        DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL cycle MONTH)) < 0
            THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS filter
ORDER BY filter, numberAbs
```

Here `number` is the one you care about. `numberAbs` and `filter` make it so you first filter by the negative values, then count up from there (so -1 is before -10).

It probably *can* be cleaned up a bit, but this should cover how to get the result you seem to be looking for.